# Get minimum starttime and max endtime in sql query

Tags: sql

I have an data which includes Processeddate , start time and end time.

I need to get the minimum startime and max endtime for one month

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results is helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the `year()` and `month()` functions.  So the idea is:

```
select year(Processeddate), month(Processeddate), min(starttime), max(endtime)
from t
group by year(Processeddate), month(Processeddate);
```

The specific functions might vary by database.

Actually, if you just want one month, then filtering is sufficient.  For January 2020:

```
select min(starttime), max(endtime)
from t
where Processeddate >= '2020-01-01' and Processeddate < '2020-02-01'
```

Date functionality varies by database, so the particular format for date constants might vary, but most databases support YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I have tried this but it seems to be not working. I need exactly like this - Processeddate in this column each day should be there, then for the each day there should be a min starttime and max endtime and this is for 1 month