# Get minimum time and max time for each day in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have an data which includes Processeddate, start time and end time. I need to get minimum starttime and max endtime for each day.

Process date should be the first coulmn

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a basic `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: Can u provide your Table Structure with some sample data and also the Expected Output?@PechiRaj

Comment: How is this different than your previous question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549175/get-minimum-starttime-and-max-endtime-in-sql-query  ?   I suspect if you supply sample data and desired results, the answer would be delivered.  A little effort on your part is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `min()` and `max()` function as shown below.

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT Cast(processedDate AS DATE) AS processedDate
        ,min(startTime) minStartTime
        ,max(endTime) maxEndTime
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY Cast(processedDate AS DATE)
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE month(processedDate) = 1
    AND year(processedDate) = 2020
ORDER BY processedDate
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5bb2dbcad1ca36516adce2a3004fcd75)